# Webpart not taking up entire space

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom sharepoint site where the Main area consists of two table cells.  The left contains the navigation and the right contains things such as Calendar webparts.  The problem is that the webparts don't take up the entire available space.  This is probably simple but how can i adjust the size of the calendar webpart so that it takes up the available space of its parent.

Comment: are you talking about the width or height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually by selecting "Adjust height to fit zone" within the webpart settings, the webpart will accommodate the space given. However, in more than one situation, I've had to manually set the height in order to get the webpart to stretch itself vertically. Give that a try!